# Laravel Json test with Bearer authentication

Tags: laravel, api, unit-testing

I'm writing a simple test to assert if an api endpoint response returns with 200 status.

My api got Bearer authentication through `sanctum` middleware.

My test function is

> ```
>     public function testExample()
>     {
> //        $response = $this->withHeader('Authorization' , 'Bearer 1|IJleXxjHgr8RaiP3Q9atJRtVCZHZKQQqBXW8NPdn')
> //                            ->getJson('/api/breeds/cat/high');
>         $response = $this->getJson('/api/breeds/cat/high', ['Authorization' => 'Bearer longtoken']);
>         $response->assertStatus(200);
>     }
> ```

routes/api.php;

```
> Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
>     Route::get('/breeds/{animal_type}/{name}', ListBreeds::class)->name('breed.list'); });
```

This test returns me with 403 / Not Authorised response.
If I use the same token and headers in Postman the route works fine.

what is it I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you setup the model properly? [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#overriding-default-models) `docs` here

Comment: It is. As I said it works if I do a curl request. example (curl --location --request GET 'http://play1/api/breeds/cat/high' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer longToken'). Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that:

```
$response = $this->withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . 'abc',
    ])->getJson('/api/breeds/cat/high');
```